# i am not getting multiple output for backtracking problem

Tags: c#, algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to solve this problem using backtracking.

Consider the following dictionary:

```
{ i, like, sam, sung, samsung, mobile, ice, cream, icecream, man, go, mango }
```

Example 1:

```
Input: "ilikesamsungmobile"

Output: i like sam sung mobile
        i like samsung mobile
```

Example 2:

```
Input: "ilikeicecreamandmango"

Output: i like ice cream and man go
        i like ice cream and mango
        i like icecream and man go
        i like icecream and mango
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace AADLHomeWorkTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool dictionary(string word)
        {

            List<string> Dict = new List<string> { "i", "like", "sam", "sung", "samsung", "mobile", "ice", "cream", "icecream", "mango ", "man", "go" };
            foreach (string x in Dict)
            {
                if (word == x)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        static bool wordbreaker(string word, int size, List<string> sol)
        {
            if (size == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (size < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word);
                Console.WriteLine("********************************");

                string test = word.Substring(0, i);
                if (dictionary(test))
                {
                    sol.Add(test + " ");
                    int x = size - i;
                    string q = word.Substring(i, size - i);
                   if( wordbreaker(q, x, sol)) return true;
                    x = size + i;
                    sol.RemoveAt(sol.Count - 1);
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string Line = "ilikesamsungmobile";
                List<string> sol = new List<string>();
                int size = Line.Length;
                if (wordbreaker(Line, size, sol))
                {
                    foreach (string x in sol)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(x);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is that the size is not getting for zero to stop the recursion.
The second is that the word is getting back after I am removing them.
And the third is how can I get multiple outputs without getting the same answer every time?

Comment: One suggestion would be to only add to `sol` at the bottom of the recursive hierarchy and never remove anything from it. That would mean passing in the prefix of the solution as an additional string argument, but it would still be cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: I will try it thanks